# Flutter - Show Camera/BarcodeScanner in Container

Tags: flutter

I would like to store the camera function in a separate container as the title already says. that means, if the camera starts it is only displayed in the red container, how could i achieve this at this point?

Picture of my Screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5INL.jpg

I use the following dependency for Scanning:

```
barcode_scan: ^1.0.0 


My Code for scanning looks like this: 

Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        showAlertDialog(context);
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Zugriff auf die Kamera wurde nicht gewährt!";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "Scan fehlgeschlagen";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check method used by this package https://github.com/elratonmaton/LastQrScanner 
or use this package instead

Dart code of this package use **AndroidView and UiKitView** 
code snippet

```
class _QRViewState extends State<LastQrScannerPreview> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var androidView = AndroidView(
      viewType: 'last_qr_scanner/qrview',
      onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
    );

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      return androidView;
    }

    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
      return UiKitView(
        viewType: 'last_qr_scanner/qrview',
        onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
        creationParams: _CreationParams.fromWidget(0, 0).toMap(),
        creationParamsCodec: StandardMessageCodec(),
      );
    }
```

and more detail on Kotlin part, you can referce source code 
Result in emulator

[image]

you can see body of Widget build use LastQrScannerPreview in example code

```
body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: LastQrScannerPreview(
                key: qrKey,
                onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
              ),
              flex: 4,
            ),
```

full example code of this package

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:last_qr_scanner/last_qr_scanner.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey qrKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  var qrText = ""; 
  var controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    final channel = controller.channel;
    controller.init(qrKey);
    channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
      switch (call.method) {
        case "onRecognizeQR":
          dynamic arguments = call.arguments;
          setState(() {
            qrText = arguments.toString();
          });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: LastQrScannerPreview(
                key: qrKey,
                onQRViewCreated: _onQRViewCreated,
              ),
              flex: 4,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text("This is the result of scan: $qrText"),
              flex: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  this.controller.toggleTorch();                  
                },
                child: Text("Toggle Torch"),
              ),
              flex: 1,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I still get the following error : Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: last_qr_scanner/qrview, null)

Comment: You can fork this package and run example. because  there are still a lot work on Kotlin

Comment: Hey, if i fork this, it works, but i want include this view in my project

Comment: does example of this package work correctly? can you add more info.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have included the LastQrScannerPreview class in my class, but I can't execute it because I get the above error. Image: https://imgur.com/a/DsBcVdB